# Starting a fire and forget async method

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Sonar/FxCop are telling us that we shouldn't use void async methods. That's ok. 
This is the current implementation:

```
private async void InitMethod(ServiceControl serviceControl)
{
    if (serviceControl != null)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => serviceControl.Execute());
    }
}

// fire and forget ... calling from a non-async method!
InitMethod(serviceControl);
```

Is this a good way or how would you refactor this method?

```
private async Task InitMethod(ServiceControl serviceControl)
{
    if (serviceControl != null)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => serviceControl.Execute());
    }
}

// fire and forget ... calling from a non-async method!
// when calling without Start then VS is complaining about "not awaiting" this method
InitMethod(serviceControl).Start();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just fire the task [without async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803012/861716).

```
private void InitMethod(ServiceControl serviceControl)
{
    if (serviceControl != null)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => serviceControl.Execute());
    }
}
```

In a proper F&F task all exception handling (including a final catch, logging, notifications) is done by the task itself, so you don't need exception handling that `async/await` provides.

Make the method name reflect what it does. I wouldn't mind a name like `FireAndForgetXyz`

Comment: Oh yes ... that is simple. Typically "can't see the forest for the trees" problem.

Comment: @gert-arnold Just be aware of consequences in case of ASP.NET if it is your case. Here is a good article [Confusing default scheduler](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: That's a useful addition. A web application should never spawn long-running tasks. (Read, for example, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: In this case we don't have an ASP.NET application but a WPF application.

Comment: In that case you may want to ensure that the application can't be closed while a task is still running.

Comment: @GertArnold So I should hold a reference to the task?

Comment: Could be a way, or a `ContinueWith` in which each task notifies it is finished.

Comment: Working for this case: `fire and forget` in ***ASP.NET WebForms*** and `windows.close()` ?